# How can I publish stable version with composer

Tags: php, git, github, composer-php, packagist

How can I publish stable version? For example, developers of Yii2 framework have stable versions on composer, but in their repository I can't find matches with their branches on repository. How do they publish stable versions? when I publish my work on packagist.org they allow me only insert my repository url

Answer (score 2):

In your GitHub repository go to `Releases` tab, then `Draft a new release`.

At any commit you can create draft and use it later or release new version right away.

Additionally you can mark release as `pre-release`.

Synchronization with Packagist is automatic (note that you need create hook, how to do it is explained [here](https://packagist.org/profile/)).

**Useful docs:**

- [Git tagging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)
- [GitHub releases](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/)
- [Semantic versioning](http://semver.org/)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a tag in your repository. Note that this works for all supported repositories, i.e. Git, Mercurial and Subversion.

The tag name must be a valid version number according to the spec, which is documented on the http://semver.org website - this applies even if you don't want to follow semantic versioning. Composer details are in the documentation: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#package-versions and https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#version (note that you do NOT add a version into the `composer.json` file when using a repository that supports tagging!).

So to release a version 1.0, you tag the commit you want it to be with any of these names

- v1.0
- 1.0
- v1.0.0
- 1.0.0

I recommend using the last one. That "v" character isn't really needed, and always using three numbers is the best way to avoid having two tags, one "1.0" and one "1.0.0" pointing to different commits, but representing the same version.

Once you push the tag to the public repository hoster (or transfer that tag to the repository when not using Git), Packagist will see it and create everything needed to inform the world about this released version.

Anything fancy, like sending release mails to a mailing list, is up to you. The Composer part of a release really is: simply create a tag with a name that is recognized as a version number, and make it public.